# Eclipse como adiciono as Packages para ser importadas depois e usa-las?

Tags: java

Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento com eclipse e java gostaria de saber onde posso adicionar várias Packages que tenho num livro para seguir os exemplo, onde posso adicionar as Packages e depois importa-las para usar? 
Obrigado *_*

Comment: Mensagem replicada, qual o nome do livro, página, capítulo e o exemplo traz as bibliotecas ou frameworks necessários?

Comment: Nome do livro é Android para programadores na página 18 tem mostrando os pacotes para ser adicionados e na página 23 tem escrito o caminho para importar a Packages só que já vi em todas pastas do meu PC e não tem a Packages Android.provider que é de um exemplo de app chamado Doodlz